# change component attribute on MDI child [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, childwindow

If I want to chand the background color of all the child windows opened i would use this:

```
For Each chld As Form In Me.MdiChildren
   chld.BackColor = Color.LightGray
Next chld
```

But how can I modify the color of a textbox found on the child forms?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each chld As frmChild In Me.MdiChildren
   chld.BackColor = Color.LightGray
Next chld
```

my mistake :(